Python3 pip does not see all versions of packages
Let me explain the essence of the problem from beginning to end.
The idea is to set up a kubernetes cluster using kubespray.
One of the steps is to install ansible and other packages described in the requirements.txt file (I will omit the attempt itself, I will only say that installing ansible version 9.6.0 (required for the last github commit for kubespray), the error looks like this (from versions: none)).
So, I put the cluster installation issue aside and focused on installing ansible version 9.6.1.
Since yum doesn't allow me to install packages from standard repositories like mirrorlist, I had to replace them with vault, so it was possible to install packages through yum directly.
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*^C sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.
Resource: https://techglimpse.com/failed-metadata-repo-appstream-centos-8/
If I try to install python and with it PIP via yum, then I get version 3.6.
If I try to install Python manually, then I can install whatever python I want, but for some reason I can't get the SSL module to work and I get this error.
https://serverspace.ru/support/help/obnovlenie-python-centos/?utm_source=yandex.ru&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=yandex.ru&utm_referrer=yandex.ru
 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/ansible-core/.
I'm trying to fix it by using the flags:
--trusted-host pypi.python.org --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Requests go through, but I get an error as an example (same if I specify ansible or ansible_core):
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jinja2>=3.0.0.0 (A problem for any package)
I also tried using the --with-openssl="/etc/pki/tls" flag when I run the ./configured command, the installation finishes seemingly without error, but the certificate problem doesn't go away.
So the only option I have is to download the packages manually, try to install them, find the dependencies, download them manually again and so on until all dependencies are installed.
Example error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=66.1.0 
I hope I have described the problem in enough detail.
PS: I tried installing ansible using centos7 and 8 image.
I also tried installing ansible using PIPX, same problem
Maybe I'm doing something wrong from the beginning
All the details above

When you say 'install Python manually' what do you mean, exactly? Do you mean you are compiling it from source? Anyhow. CentOS was discontinued some time ago. You'll probably have a better experience using a supported distribution like Rocky Linux (which should be pretty much a drop-in replacement for CentOS) and I believe Rocky has all modern Python versions available in its package manager repositories by default.

When I say I install python manually, I mean downloading the tar.gz archive, then running a ./configuration script or something similar, then “make” and “make install. Manually installing python is just trying to run the absible v9.6.0 installation from a .whl file that was downloaded from pypi.org. When installing with python version 3.6, the error explicitly says you need a version higher than 3.9 (which is not available to me through standard tools like yum)

@AlexeyArhipov Higher version of Python requires higher version of OpenSSL so you cannot just download python-3.9.tar.gz and expect it to built and work. For higher Python versions try conda, it installs all necessary dependencies. Ansible 4.10.0 works with Python 3.6.
